# how to elegantly get the only element from a Map

Tags: java, dictionary, get

I have a `Map` that will hold one and only one `Entry`. I know it for sure since it holds the result of executing a query like this:

```
SELECT MAX(COLUMN) FROM SOMETABLE
```

In the worst case, it should return null.
Now I'm trying to get that result. I'm facing two approaches, but I think there should be a better solution.

My Test code:

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
result.put("maxColumn", new Integer(1));
```

Solution 1:

```
Integer maxValue = (Integer) result.get(result.keySet().iterator().next());
```

Solution 2:

```
Integer maxValue = (Integer) result.values().toArray()[0];
```

Is there a better way to do this? Which one do you find more declarative / less expensive?

Edit: I'm not allowed to use any other data structure because `Map<String, Object>` is the result type returned from the persistence API I'm using.

Comment: A Map is a collection of items. Why would you use this if there's only ever (at most) 1 entry?

Comment: @splungebob I would guess it's a part of the API of whatever SQL library he's using (I assume it's SQL given his query).

Comment: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DaveJarvis I just heard about codereview. Is it possible to move the question there?

Comment: I don't want to close this as it should be moved...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest and cleanest is option 2, because it goes directly to the value (not via `get()`):

```
Integer i = (Integer) result.values().toArray()[0];
```

But it's a bit ugly and has a cast. I would be inclined to refactor this into a typed utility method that your whole team could use:

```
public class MapUtils {

    public static <T> T getSingleValue(Map<String, Object> map) {
        return (T) map.values().toArray()[0];
    }
}
```

By *typing* the method, you avoid the ugly cast in your code, because you would use it like this:

```
Integer maxValue = MapUtils.getSingleValue(result);
```

Here java can use *type inference* to determine the you are expecting. By not having the cast, you can change the type of `maxValue` and the code will still work. With the cast you would have to change both the type *and* the cast to match.

Comment: I guess you meant `Integer maxValue = MapUtils.getSingleValue(result)`. Sorry but I don't get how type inference works in this case, even after reading [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypeInference.html). None of the parameters are of type T. Shouldn't I invoke this method by specifying the type parameter, as in `Integer maxValue = MapUtils.<T>getSingleValue(result)`? (I admit I haven't tested it yet)

Comment: You *can* invoke it by specifying the type, but you don't have to in certain circumstances, such as when the returned value is assigned to a variable, here java can figure out the the type T is Integer. And ye, I did mean MapUtils (I changed the name if the utility class when I realised it had more general applicability than your usage.

Answer (score 3):

If you are absolutely sure there is one and only one element:

```
Integer maxValue = map.values().iterator().next()
```

or

```
List<Integer> integerList = new ArrayList<Integer>(map.values());
Integer maxValue = integerList.get(0);
```

or

```
for (Integer maxValue : map.values) {
    doStuffWithMaxValue(maxValue);           
}
```

Casting is not such a good idea.

Comment: The return type of the method I'm using is ArrayList<String, Object> and not ArrayList<String, Integer>, so I can't see the way to implement your solution avoiding the cast. I'm sorry my question wasn't clear enough, skipping those important details.

Comment: Regarding your second suggestion, it won't work because `map.values()` returns a `Collection`, and there's no constructor for `ArrayList<E>(Collection)`

Comment: @DiegoAlfonso Actually there is: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html

Comment: My bad. I don't know why I thought it was ArrayList(Set). I should have checked javadoc first